# Use custom function inside Firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a long function that I'm using in multiple places in my code but I've realized my function is not even being called. Copying-pasting would lead to a disaster. Are there any way to call a custom function inside of a Firebase function?

***My test:*** 
I call this function at the first line after the trigger but nothing appears on the console logs.

```
function test()
{
    console.log('function executed');
}
```

Comment: Yup, you should be able to call regular JavaScript functions from within your Cloud Functions. If that doesn't work for you, share the [minimal **complete** code that can be used to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I haven't tested completely but when I've used return statement in my function the problem has resolved. Is this possible, so I can add it as answer?

Comment: If that solved it, it is clearly possible. :) But it is impossible for us to say why that is, given the incomplete repro in your question. That also means that an answer (while valid for you), will be of no use to folks who may encounter problems in the future. It's really most helpful if you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that others can benefit from your experience.